# CronExpression to represent from x to y

Tags: cron

I'd like to achieve the following with a [CronExpression](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E12058_01/doc/doc.1014/e12030/cron_expressions.htm).

Start at: 04.06.2017
Fire every Day at 01:00:00
End at: 09.09.2018 23:59:59
So far I only can say: 
Start at 04.06.2017
Fire every Day (at 01:00:00)
End at: 31.12.2018 23:59:59
I achieve this with the following expression:

```
0 0 1 4/1 6 ? 2017-2018
```

Is there a possibility to set a specific finishing date?

Comment: Not with a single expression. You will need at least two.

Comment: How would both expression look then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could think about something like this:

```
1) 0 0 1 4/1 6 ? 2017
2) 0 0 1 * 7-12 ? 2017
3) 0 0 1 * 1-8 ? 2018
4) 0 0 1 1-9 9 ? 2018
```

Comment: And if I want it to stop on 09.09.2018 22:00:00
Then i have to modify it to 4) 0 0 1 1-8 9 ? 2018
5) 0 0 1-22 9 9 ? 2018. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, you can test it for example here: http://www.cronmaker.com/ Just remove year from your expression.